# in sql how can i display sal as null when grouped by dept,grades for missing grades in a dept

Tags: sql

```
select e.deptno,s.grade,sum(sal)
from emp e ,  salgrade s
where (e.sal between s.losal and s.hisal)

 group by e.deptno,s.grade
 order by e.deptno,s.grade;
```

i'm unable to fit in the query to show 0 sal for missing grades

Comment: Show example data with desired query results.

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

You want a `LEFT JOIN`.  Presuming you have table with all departments:

```
select d.deptno, s.grade, sum(e.sal)
from departments d left join
     emp e
     on e.deptno = d.deptno left join
     salgrade s
     on e.sal between s.losal and s.hisal
group by d.deptno, s.grade
order by d.deptno, s.grade;
```

Comment: desired result example:

Comment: dept no  grade  sum(sal)
10            1         507
10             2        1066
10            3          0
10            4         0 it must be like this when there are no grade 3,4 employees in dept 10